# Compute Manhattan distance from origin given a set of left-right-step directions

Tags: programming-challenge, rust, taxicab-geometry

I am solving the problems for Advent of Code 2016 to learn Rust programming. The prompt for the first problem can be summarized:

I start at position 0,0 on a regular grid. I am given a set of directions to get to a location. I can only travel in "steps" on this grid, and I am only given directions in the form (e.g.):

```
R5, L2, L1, R1, R3, R3, L3, R3, R4, L2, R4, L4, R4
```

Where the first character is the direction to turn right or left and the following number is the number of steps to take. I need to compute the Manhattan distance between my starting point and the ending point.

The instructions are saved in a text file called "2016-1.txt".

```
use std::fs;

struct Pos {
    facing: char,
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

fn split_dir(dir_str: &str) -> Vec<&str> {
    dir_str.split(", ").collect()
}

fn update_facing(rel_dir: &char, face_char: &char) -> char {
    if *rel_dir == 'L' {
        match face_char {
            'N' => 'W',
            'S' => 'E',
            'E' => 'N',
            'W' => 'S',
            _ => 'I', // Is there a better way to handle the catch-all?
        }
    } else {
        match face_char {
            'N' => 'E',
            'S' => 'W',
            'E' => 'S',
            'W' => 'N',
            _ => 'I',
        }
    }
}

fn update_x(pos_x: i32, face_char: char, move_num: i32) -> i32 {
    match face_char {
        'E' => pos_x + move_num,
        'W' => pos_x - move_num,
        _   => pos_x
    }
}

fn update_y(pos_y: i32, face_char: char, move_num: &i32) -> i32 {
    match face_char {
        'N' => pos_y + move_num,
        'S' => pos_y - move_num,
        _   => pos_y
    }
}

fn get_manhattan_dist(pos_x: i32, pos_y: i32, origin_x: i32, origin_y: i32) -> i32 {
    (pos_x - origin_x).abs() + (pos_y - origin_y).abs()
}

fn main() {
    let s = fs::read_to_string("2016-1.txt")
        .expect("Failed to read file.");

    let split: Vec<&str> = split_dir(&s);

    let mut pos: Pos = Pos {x: 0, y: 0, facing: 'N'};

    for inst in split {
        // Update direction
        let rel_dir = inst.chars().nth(0).unwrap(); // Get first character of the instruction
        pos.facing = update_facing(&rel_dir, &pos.facing);

        // Update position
        let move_num = &inst[1..].parse::<i32>().unwrap();
        pos.x = update_x(pos.x, pos.facing, *move_num);
        pos.y = update_y(pos.y, pos.facing, &move_num);
    }

    let dist = get_manhattan_dist(pos.x, pos.y, 0, 0);
    println!("{}", dist);
}
```

I am particularly interested in error handling. Particularly in the `update_facing` function. This is my first Rust program, so all advice is warranted as well.

Comment: *am particularly interested in error handling* — what do you want to *happen* on errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks more complicated than necessary for this task.

The first thing I noticed was the directions N, E, S, W. There is no need to explicitly name them. It is simpler to just define a direction as a 2-dimensional tuple:

```
struct Direction {
    dx: i32,
    dy: i32
}
```

That's the essence of a direction. As the next step, I remembered that rotating such a direction by 90 degrees is quite simple. It just involves swapping the coordinates and reversing one of them. To get these right, I manually checked all the combinations after writing this code:

```
impl Direction {
    fn left(&self) -> Direction { Direction { dx: self.dy, dy: -self.dx } }
    fn right(&self) -> Direction { Direction { dx: -self.dy, dy: self.dx } }
}
```

By these simple definitions, I avoided dealing with N, E, S, W at all.

When I tested the program using the example you provided, my IDE added a trailing newline to the file, as is usual for text files. Then the program crashed because it could not parse an empty string. Therefore I changed `split_dir(&s)` into `split_dir(s.trim())`, and it worked.

To understand the main program, I separated it into the part that deals with input and output, and the processing part in between. To do this, I defined this function:

```
fn manhattan_distance(s: &str) -> i32 {
    ...
}
```

I inlined the `split_dir`, `update_x`, `update_y` and `get_manhattan_dist` functions, and in the end my code became:

```
use std::fs;

struct Pos {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
    dir: Direction,
}

struct Direction {
    dx: i32,
    dy: i32,
}

impl Direction {
    fn left(&self) -> Direction {
        Direction {
            dx: self.dy,
            dy: -self.dx,
        }
    }

    fn right(&self) -> Direction {
        Direction {
            dx: -self.dy,
            dy: self.dx,
        }
    }
}

fn manhattan_distance(s: &str) -> i32 {
    let steps = s.trim().split(", ");

    let mut pos = Pos {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        dir: Direction { dx: 0, dy: -1 },
    };

    for step in steps {
        let (turn, dist) = step.split_at(1);

        // Update direction
        pos.dir = match turn {
            "L" => pos.dir.left(),
            "R" => pos.dir.right(),
            _ => panic!("invalid turn {} in step {}", turn, step),
        };

        // Update position
        let dist = dist.parse::<i32>().unwrap();
        pos.x += pos.dir.dx * dist;
        pos.y += pos.dir.dy * dist;
    }

    pos.x.abs() + pos.y.abs()
}

fn main() {
    let s = fs::read_to_string("2016-1.txt").expect("Failed to read file.");

    println!("{}", manhattan_distance(&s));
}
```

What's left now are some automatic tests. The function `manhattan_distance` is well-prepared for that since it has no side-effects, does not need any input or output, gets its parameter as a simple string and just returns its result.

And here are some example tests. You should add some more to explore other interesting cases, like crossing the x or y axis. The current tests might also pass if you omit the calls to `abs`.

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use crate::manhattan_distance;

    #[test]
    fn manhattan_distance_example() {
        assert_eq!(11, manhattan_distance("R5, L2, L1, R1, R3, R3, L3, R3, R4, L2, R4, L4, R4"))
    }

    #[test]
    fn manhattan_distance_empty() {
        assert_eq!(0, manhattan_distance(" \t\n"))
    }

    #[test]
    fn manhattan_distance_simple() {
        assert_eq!(13, manhattan_distance("R8, L5"))
    }

    #[test]
    fn manhattan_distance_rectangle() {
        assert_eq!(0, manhattan_distance("R8, L5, L8, L5"))
    }
}
```

Your code is a good working base, it was just longer than necessary. I also changed most of the variable names to be a little more precise and easier to grasp for a casual reader of the code. For example, since the task talks about "steps", it's only natural to name the corresponding variables in the code also "steps" and "step".

Since this is my first real program in Rust as well, I don't know what the really idiomatic Rust code looks like, I hope I could improve the code nevertheless.

To check whether I made any typical beginner's mistakes, I ran `cargo-clippy`, and I didn't get any complaints.

Comment: I think one more thing that'd help with your new `manhattan_distance` function is making a struct named something like `Step` with the `turn` and `dist` fields. Then `manhattan_distance` would take in a `impl Iterator<Type=Step>` instead of a `&str`. This way you separate the input parsing from the algorithm logic, so it can handle input formatted in a variety of ways. Then you could do something like `s.trim().split(", ").map(Step::from_str)` when passing the input to the function.

Answer (score 3):

I concur with Roland's comments, but wanted to add this:

```
    match face_char {
        'N' => 'W',
        'S' => 'E',
        'E' => 'N',
        'W' => 'S',
        _ => 'I', // Is there a better way to handle the catch-all?
    }
```

Rust has a macro for this scenario: `unreachable!()`. It is a standard way to indicate that a certain case should never happen in practice.